# Specifying --diskSizeGb when running a dataflow template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to use a Google dataflow template to export data from Bigtable to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). I'm following the gcloud command details [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloudbigtabletosequencefile). However, when running I get a warning and associated error where the [suggested fix](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#tsg-rpc-timeout) is to add workers (--numWorkers), increase the attached disk size (--diskSizeGb). However, I see no way to execute the Google provided template while passing those parameters. Amy I missing something?

Reviewing a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467089/facing-outofmemoryexception-while-exporting-bigtable-tables-to-google-cloud-stor), it seems like there is a way to do this. Can someone explain how?

Comment: I believe this isn't possible now with a google-provided template (or any other existing templates). You can set those parameters in your own code before compiling it into a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parameters like `numWorkers` and `diskSizeGb` are [Dataflow wide pipeline options](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options). You should be able to specify them like so

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME \
--gcs-location LOCATION --num-workers=$NUM_WORKERS --diskSizeGb=$DISK_SIZE
```

Let me know if you have furthr questions

Comment: Thanks for responding! Howegver, when I do this, I get the following error: ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.jobs.run) unrecognized arguments: --diskSizeGb=250. The documentation here doesn't include that parameter: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run

Comment: This also continues to give me the same error. Did you ever figure this out @MichaelGreen ?