# Dataflow - State persistence specs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

We are considering using Beam/Dataflow for stateful processing. We understand that states persistence is managed by Windmill/Persistent Disks [1].

Are they known limitations of this persistence technology vs. alternatives (e.g. RocksDB for Flink) ?

Thanks !

[1] [Dataflow - State persistence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837451/dataflow-state-persistence/69846214#69846214)

Comment: What you mean with Windmill DB, it is not clear for me, can you explain better or add some reference ? About the use of Beam and Flink, first the concepts of Sdk/Runners/Engines have to be clarified, because somehow, you can be using both. This article has a good clarification about it [Apache Beam: How Beam Runs on Top of Flink](https://flink.apache.org/ecosystem/2020/02/22/apache-beam-how-beam-runs-on-top-of-flink.html)

Comment: @ewertonvsilva Ok, let me ask first how is state persistence managed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837451/dataflow-state-persistence

Answer (score 1):

Apache Beam doesn't actually execute pipelines. I expresses the semantics of the pipeline and provides an SDK for describing user code. But Apache Beam is designed to run on any runner, like :

- Dataflow (which is powered by Windmill);
- Flink;
- Spark;
- and so on...

That's actually one of the main draws of Beam - that it is portable and separates the pipeline semantics from the execution environment.

About Windmill:

> Windmill is a process running on user VMs in streaming Dataflow jobs. It is responsible for performing the streaming shuffle between workers, persisting and maintaining the consistency of pipeline state.

Windmill and persistent storage on disk are **the same thing**. Windmill **stores pipeline state on Persistent Disks.**

Users have the option of specifying a disk size when starting the pipeline using --diskSizeGb. When a job is reloaded the disks from the previous job are transferred to the new job. You can see an [Stack about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696682/specifying-disksizegb-when-running-a-dataflow-template).

About Flink, is another [**runner**](https://github.com/apache/beam#runners) so, Dataflow and Flink are different runners. RockDB also use disk storage and the advantage of using it can vary, [this article](https://flink.apache.org/2021/01/18/rocksdb.html) provides some statements about it.

In summary, both approaches will use disk storage and other means, and also there is a huge dependency on the type of disk used, environment. That's not a simple comparison, I suggest you test both environments if it's a really important matter.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Would you mind 1) Move your answer to this ticket as it is more generic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837451/dataflow-state-persistence 2) Add references for Windmill. I give you the +1 then. Thanks !

Comment: Sure, though the purpose of this ticket was to get more clarity of pros/cons. Glad to get your input here, too ;) Also, feel free to add your input about configuration (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835758/dataflow-state-db-config) and possible replacement (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835768/dataflow-state-db-replacement).