# Dataflow - State persistence config

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

We are considering using Beam/Dataflow for stateful processing. We understand that states persistence is managed by Windmill/Persistent Disks [1].

Is it possible to access those disks ? What can be configured ?

Thanks !

[1] [Dataflow - State persistence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837451/dataflow-state-persistence/69846214#69846214)

Comment: Can you provide more details about Windmill DB?? Its a hardware? an application? an OS? a Database?. Please provide a reference link or documentation link. If you are referring on how to make your own beam/dataflow steps, the answer is yes. Besides the available templates you can create a dataflow job from code, check [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/beam-creating-a-pipeline).

Comment: @Betjens Ok, let me ask first how is state persistence managed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837451/dataflow-state-persistence